# The html "maxlength" attribute does not count to commas when applied to chrome, but calculates in IE. Why is this?

Tags: html

html code   :
    input class="field" type="text" name="budget01" id="budget01" size="12" maxlength="8" runat="server"  onchange="calSignBudget(name);addCommas(this);">

ps:
calSignBudget(name); and addCommas(this);
It is a javascript that adds a comma function. It does not count commas in Chrome, but it does in IE.

Comment: Can you share the code here?

Comment: html: <input class="field" type="text" name="budget01" id="budget01" size="12" maxlength="12" runat="server" onchange="calSignBudget(name);addCommas(this);">

Comment: javascript: function calSignBudget(budge) {
    var isSignBudget = 0;
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 12;i++){
        isSignBudget += getNumeric(getObjectValue('budget' + lpad(i.toString(), 2, '0')));
    }
    var allowBudget = getNumeric(getObjectValue('allowBudget'));

    setObjectValue('isSignBudget', addCommas(isSignBudget));
    setObjectValue('nonSignBudget', addCommas(allowBudget - isSignBudget));
}

Comment: javascript :function addCommas(obj){ var s = ""; var flag = false; if (obj != null && isObj(obj)){ if (isObj(obj.value)) {s = obj.value; flag = true;} else s = "" + obj; } else return "";if (s != null && s.length > 0) { s = deleteCommas(s);var sValue = s;        var r = ""; var arr = s.split("."); if (arr != null && arr.length > 0){sValue = arr[0];           if (arr.length > 1) r = "." + arr[1]; var sRegExp = new RegExp('(-?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})');while (sRegExp.test(sValue)){sValue = sValue.replace(sRegExp, '$1,$2');            }if (flag) obj.value = sValue + r;else return sValue + r;}}return s;}